# sql where clause for managedQuery android method

Tags: android, database, image, where-clause

I am trying to write the parameters to the managedQuery method in android and having trouble with the WHERE clause,  here is what i wrote;

```
Cursor imageCursor;

// lots of other junk

String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};

imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA = filename, proj, null );
```

"filename" is a `string` variable holding the path of an image,  example `/mnt/sdcard/pic05.png`

I want it to return a cursor holding a record that is the same record for the pic05.png image and the cursor returned would hold the TITLE column information for this specific picture.  How did i mess up the sql WHERE CLAUSE?  I thought that my syntax must be wroing on the where clause

Comment: aren't you missing a few quotes ? (these : ")

Comment: plus, you are using the projection as selection argument, which won't work, as you don't need arguments given the current shape of your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add '  ' around filename. Try this

```
   Cursor imageCursor;

     // lots of other junk

       String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};
    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";

     imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, selection, null, null );
```